# setx Causes Windows Explorer to Scroll to Top

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I have a folder that contains a lot of batch files -- more than can be displayed onscreen at one time in Windows Explorer. Some of these are clustered together, and need to be executed in sequence (but not in the *same* batch, as intermediate steps are necessary outside that which can be handled by batch files).

One of my files works as expected, but when I run that file, it causes the Explorer window to scroll to the top of the list. This isn't crippling -- but it's a mild irritant, as it distracts me from which file I ran last. (Also, it's just *weird*, and I'd like to understand what's going on.)

I've isolated the problem to a `setx` call: If I comment out this line, the batch file executes with no effect on the Explorer window that displays the directory in which it resides. If I uncomment the line and double-click the file, the batch file executes *and* its Explorer window scrolls to the top.

For diagnostics, I slimmed this down to a single line: I created a file named **Test.bat**, with only the following line of content:

```
setx TestValue abc
```

I put in it a folder with enough files in it that they were not all visible at once -- and, because it starts with a *T*, **Test.bat** displayed near the bottom. When I double-clicked it, the window scrolled to the top.

I'm using Windows 10. And tried this on another computer (with the same result) just to be certain it wasn't a quirk of my original machine.

Is this behavior something that can be negated with a command switch or a change to the Windows configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why?

`setx` command sends an [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to all top-level windows to notify the changes to the environment (`lParam` is `Environment`).

This causes the explorer windows to reprocess their environment and in this process the file list is repositioned.

How to solve?

There is not any way in `setx` to disable the message sending, and I don't know a way (using only the OS) to indicate to the `explorer` windows to not process the received message (that needs to be processed so new started processes could see the new variable).

The only way I see to deal with this "problem" is to directly write the variables into the registry and only call `setx` when you need to inform the rest of the windows of the environment changes.

Comment: Thanks! That's the kind of in-depth reply that makes Stack Overflow such a valuable resource. (Even if I can't really solve it, at least I know not to bang my head against the wall trying.) Upvote, and I'm marking you correct, unless someone else comes along with some magic that overrides the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` behavior.